# Is there a way to make my neural network discard inputs with bad results from learning?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

What I want to achieve is this: If my desired outputs are [1, 2, 3, 4] I would rather have my network produce this output:

[0.99, 2.01, 999, 4.01]

than say this:

[0.94, 1.88, 3.12, 4.1]

So I'd rather have a few very accurate outputs and the rest completely off, than have them all be decent but no more than that. My question is, is there a known way to do this? If not, would it make sense to remove the inputs that produce poor outputs, and redo the learning phase?

Answer (score 3):

I assume [1, 2, 3, 4] are the desired outputs for different examples for a regression task. Sound like you need a different loss function. From your description it seems you don't care how big the error is if it's bigger than some value. Try the [Huber loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss)(in [Pytorch](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.SmoothL1Loss.html#smoothl1loss) and [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/Huber)). Examples that are far from the expected value won't produce big gradients (:

Comment: Yes that's correct. Thank, I will check that out

Comment: Can I just make the gradient 0 if the error is too large? So I have 2 loss funtions, depending on the error. One is zero and the other one is quadratic or whatever else

Comment: If you implement the loss function to be a constant, when the error is too large, you’ll get this behavior. The best way to achieve it is using torch.where/tf.where. Note that this might not be optimal. If many examples have an error larger than the threshold, the model won’t train or it will overfit on a subset of the examples. 
Can you provide more context?

Comment: I'm trying to predict stock prices so the idea is after an initial phase of learning, when no error is very large and the network has a decent grasp of the function, to ditch the worst outputs in order to get better accuracy on the good outputs

Answer (score 0):

Use genetic algorithm. Run like 25 neural networks at once and choose the most successful  one. This method is similar to evolution, which is why it is very effective. I created a model like this with similar sized training data as yours and it reached an overall error rate of 0.06% in a second. Don’t get rid of nodes. Instead, eliminate the bad networks. However, this doesn’t produce extremely high error rates if that is what you want.

Comment: They don't have to be high, I just wanted to say that if error is larger than x it might as well be a gazillion, I don't care. But you're just saying to run the network many times, not necessarily at the same time?

Comment: Yes. Also consider increasing or decreasing your mutation amount (random increase to weights) based on how well the networks are performing.

Comment: This will help increase network accuracy, but doesn't address the specific question about prioritising a few correct outputs over punishing very incorrect outputs. Addressing this ultimately comes down to the loss function, as that determines how to handle bad outputs.